# Chaining queries with sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

In sequelize I want to do something like chaining findAll function calls.

I would like to make a findAll on a model like

```
const newYorkers = await People.findAll({ where: { city: 'New York' } });
```

and then use `newYorkers` as parameter for a function, that makes another findAll on that

```
const get5ThAvenueInhabitants = (citiesInhabitants) => {
  return await citiesInhabitants.findAll({ where: { street: '5th Avenue' } });
};

get5ThAvenueInhabitants(newYorkers);
```

That won't work, because after the first findAll, the result isn't a model anymore, but an array of results.

Is it possible to achieve this with sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is findAll `People` who live in `New York` and `5th Avenue`, why don't you use `and` operator?

It would be as simple as

```js
const newYorkers = People.findAll({ 
  where: { 
       city: 'New York',
       street: '5th Avenue',
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Comment: I want to filter the data before I use them as a parameter for get5ThAvenueInhabitants. I don't want to give get5ThAvenueInhabitants the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

First besides what you asking, I don't understand the logic behind the function `get5ThAvenueInhabitants()`. As the previous answer, you can filter directly using `where: { city: 'New York', street: '5th Avenue'}`. There is no need to query first 'New York' and then  '5th Avenue'.

Now coming back on what you really ask, about chaining the request you can use async/await like this:

```
const mainFunction = async () => {
    const newYorkers = await People.findAll({ where: { city: 'New York' } });
    get5ThAvenueInhabitants(newYorkers);
}
```

This way, the `newYorkers` will wait untill all the data is fetch and then proceed to `get5ThAvenueInhabitants()` .

Comment: Yes, I forgot the await in my example. I edited it right now. But I don't think that it works now. The findAll in get5ThAvenueInhabitants will be called on an array of instances. But findAll only works with models.

Comment: That's what I mean, you can't actually call `findAll` on `newYorkers`, you can use `filter` to do that, but again. not really necessary when  you can do it at once on the first query.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, `People.findAll({ where: { city: 'New York' } });` returns an array of `instances` and not a `model`. The `instance` object does expose methods like `destroy`, `update`, etc., and so you can, in a sense, do a kind of query "chaining", by using the methods on a returned instance, like this:

```
People.findAll({ where: { city: 'New York' } }).then(people => {
     people.forEach(person => {
         person.destroy();
     })
 });
```

To filter the returned collection in your application code, as opposed to using a DB query, you could do something like this:

```
 People.findAll({ where: { city: 'New York' } }).then(people => {
     people.filter(person => {
        if(person.street === '5th Avenue'){
            return person;
        }
     })
 });
```

Comment: The solution to use `filter` for the next "queries" would be my approach, if there is no possibility to chain `findAll`s. But I wonder if the performance of `Array.filter` will be as good as `findAll`.